# Javafx analog for android RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, javafx, fxml

I was working for a while with android and liked useful class RelativeLayout there. It helps to position elements on the screen easily, relative to each other.

Not long ago I've switched to javafx. Sometimes I feel I need this useful class, but I couldn't find any analog. Does anybody knows any way to make fxml layout elements acting similarly?

Comment: I don't think there is an equivalent. The nearest is probably `AnchorPane`, where you can place nodes relative to the edge of the parent container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no exact equivalent for this in JavaFX, but there are some layouts that allow you to get similar effects.

[`GridPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) allows you to specify row and column indices for it's children. If the indices of children that are supposed to be placed next to each other differ by 1, they should be placed next to each other. You can also make a child use multiple rows/columns by setting the `rowSpan`/`columnSpan`. There are several constraints that influence resizing of the node.

[`VBox`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html)/[`HBox`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html) allow you to place nodes next to each other vertically/horizontally.

[`AnchorPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html) allows you to specify distances from the sides where a node should be placed.

Depending on your required constraints a `AnchorPane` containing (possibly nested) `HBox`es and `VBox`es could reproduce the desired layout, but using `GridPane`, if it works for you, is much simpler.